# Why question for Best tool is wrong, but for Good are ok?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Why question with word **best** are considered wrong and downvoted automatically? **Even if certain criteria are clear when something is the best**. We are looking for *best software* but we can ask only for *software*.

From other side asking for *good software* is ok.

- [FTP file editor and uploader that's also a code editor?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/150/good-ftp-file-editor-and-uploader-thats-also-a-code-editor)
- [RSS feed notifier with easy StackExchange integration and proxy support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/455/good-rss-feed-notifier-with-easy-stackexchange-integration-and-proxy-support)
- [Tool for code coverage of (unit tests in) C#](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-is-a-good-tool-for-code-coverage-of-unit-tests-in-c)

Why *good* is so different from *best*.

Sample *best* question, title edited after many commets to change title, few people prefer leaving *best*.

- [Very space-efficient freeware file compressor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/439/most-space-efficient-freeware-file-compressor/446#446)

Comments:

> Questions asking for the most/best/greatest are far too often asking for data that is subjective, based in personal opinion or may be completely unquantifiable.
>
> If your answer (*It doesn't ask for a good file compressor. It is specifically asking for the best, or in the case of this question the most efficient.* is true, **that means superlative questions in general ("best", "most X", etc.) are off-topic**. Is that a road we want to go down? (not asking you specifically, but anyone)

Comment: I redact `good` out of questions as well. So, its no different.

Comment: What is wrong with *good*, if asker is looking for good software?

Comment: Well, are there askers looking for *bad* software? *shudder*

Comment: Maybe not, but it is really reason to downote whole question? With this rule we will kill many newbie on this site, not everyone knows this **best** rule.

Comment: no, its a reason to edit the question, not to downvote it.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer That depends whether “best” is a bad formulation (→ edit) or a symptom of a question that doesn't specify anything else (→ close).

Comment: @Gilles I Agree.

Answer (score 2):

Not speaking about the down-votes, but phrasing generally: "the best tool" is always *subjective* ("One man's owl is another man's nightingale"). We try to be *objective*: Answers given should of course meet the questioner's requirements, but also be useful for future visitors.

So avoid asking for "the best X". And as probably nobody is looking for "a bad X", asking for "a good X" is like asking for "wet water". Rather ask for an X that meets certain conditions.

Comment: Asking for *most efficient* is also not recommended?

Comment: Depends. But *most likely* falls into the same category: You're looking for an *efficient* X, that's OK. But "most efficient" again might be subjective. And why should one recommend the "least efficient" X? Ask for *water*, not for *wet water* ;)

Comment: @MariuszS Most likely you want a "sufficiently efficient" so just stating "efficient" should be enough. Take compression as example, if you want to have an archiver with the "most efficient" compression algorithm, no answer could be correct that does not clearly bring facts that THIS is the maximum on compression that is theoretically possible.

Comment: This has also big side effect, users google for best tools and will never be redirected here. This is good for us?

Comment: @MariuszS I don't believe this, how you know that googlers search for "best tool" or "good tool" instead of "tool"?

Comment: maybe you're right, just guessing